# Incorrect string value: '\xD8\xA7\xD9\x84\xD8\xB9...' for column 'DisplayName' at row 1

Tags: c#, mysql, collation, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I'm getting the below exception when running server-side code.

> ```
> FATAL 2018-04-25 14:41:59,757 [1    ] Abp.AbpBootstrapper             
> - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. --->
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Incorrect string value:
> '\xD8\xA7\xD9\x84\xD8\xB9...' for column 'DisplayName' at row 1 --->
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Incorrect string value:
> '\xD8\xA7\xD9\x84\xD8\xB9...' for column 'DisplayName' at row 1    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> at
> MySqlConMyCompanytor.Core.ResultSet.<ReadResultSetHeaderAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\projects\mysqlconMyCompanytor\src\MySqlConMyCompanytor\Core\ResultSet.cs:line
> 43    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(ResultSet
> resultSet) in
> C:\projects\mysqlconMyCompanytor\src\MySqlConMyCompanytor\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line
> 92    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.<ReadFirstResultSetAsync>d__65.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\projects\mysqlconMyCompanytor\src\MySqlConMyCompanytor\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line
> 297
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.<CreateAsync>d__64.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\projects\mysqlconMyCompanytor\src\MySqlConMyCompanytor\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line
> 287
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> MySqlConMyCompanytor.Core.TextCommandExecutor.<ExecuteReaderAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\projects\mysqlconMyCompanytor\src\MySqlConMyCompanytor\Core\TextCommandExecutor.cs:line
> 70
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior) in
> C:\projects\mysqlconMyCompanytor\src\MySqlConMyCompanytor\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlCommand.cs:line
> 172    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySqlRelationalCommand.<ExecuteAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySqlRelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConMyCompanytion
> conMyCompanytion, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2
> parameterValues)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConMyCompanytion
> conMyCompanytion, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConMyCompanytion
> conMyCompanytion)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConMyCompanytion
> conMyCompanytion)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.MySqlBatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1
> commandBatches, IRelationalConMyCompanytion conMyCompanytion)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1
> entries)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1
> entriesToSave)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean
> acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean
> acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)    at
> Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpDbContext.SaveChanges() in
> D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\AbpDbContext.cs:line
> 198    at
> Abp.Zero.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpZeroCommonDbContext`3.SaveChanges() in
> D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore\Zero\EntityFrameworkCore\AbpZeroCommonDbContext.cs:line
> 154    at
> MyCompany.MyProject.EntityFrameworkCore.Seed.Host.DefaultLanguagesCreator.AddLanguageIfNotExists(ApplicationLanguage
> language) in
> C:\Users\MyName\Source\Workspaces\Workspace\FoodKioskSolution\MyCompany.MyProject\src\MyCompany.MyProject.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\Seed\Host\DefaultLanguagesCreator.cs:line
> 59    at
> MyCompany.MyProject.EntityFrameworkCore.Seed.Host.DefaultLanguagesCreator.CreateLanguages()
> in
> C:\Users\MyName\Source\Workspaces\Workspace\FoodKioskSolution\MyCompany.MyProject\src\MyCompany.MyProject.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\Seed\Host\DefaultLanguagesCreator.cs:line
> 47    at
> MyCompany.MyProject.EntityFrameworkCore.Seed.Host.DefaultLanguagesCreator.Create()
> in
> C:\Users\MyName\Source\Workspaces\Workspace\FoodKioskSolution\MyCompany.MyProject\src\MyCompany.MyProject.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\Seed\Host\DefaultLanguagesCreator.cs:line
> 40    at
> MyCompany.MyProject.EntityFrameworkCore.Seed.Host.InitialHostDbBuilder.Create()
> in
> C:\Users\MyName\Source\Workspaces\Workspace\FoodKioskSolution\MyCompany.MyProject\src\MyCompany.MyProject.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\Seed\Host\InitialHostDbBuilder.cs:line
> 15    at
> MyCompany.MyProject.EntityFrameworkCore.Seed.SeedHelper.SeedHostDb(MyProjectDbContext
> context) in
> C:\Users\MyName\Source\Workspaces\Workspace\FoodKioskSolution\MyCompany.MyProject\src\MyCompany.MyProject.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\Seed\SeedHelper.cs:line
> 25    at
> MyCompany.MyProject.EntityFrameworkCore.Seed.SeedHelper.WithDbContext[TDbContext](IIocResolver
> iocResolver, Action`1 contextAction) in
> C:\Users\MyName\Source\Workspaces\Workspace\FoodKioskSolution\MyCompany.MyProject\src\MyCompany.MyProject.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\Seed\SeedHelper.cs:line
> 41    at
> MyCompany.MyProject.EntityFrameworkCore.Seed.SeedHelper.SeedHostDb(IIocResolver
> iocResolver) in
> C:\Users\MyName\Source\Workspaces\Workspace\FoodKioskSolution\MyCompany.MyProject\src\MyCompany.MyProject.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\Seed\SeedHelper.cs:line
> 17    at
> MyCompany.MyProject.EntityFrameworkCore.MyProjectEntityFrameworkModule.PostInitialize()
> in
> C:\Users\MyName\Source\Workspaces\Workspace\FoodKioskSolution\MyCompany.MyProject\src\MyCompany.MyProject.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\MyProjectEntityFrameworkModule.cs:line
> 46    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)   
> at Abp.AbpBootstrapper.Initialize() in
> D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\AbpBootstrapper.cs:line 155
> ```

Exception is in file **DefaultLanguagesCreator.cs**:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Abp.Localization;

namespace MyCompany.MyProject.EntityFrameworkCore.Seed.Host
{
    public class DefaultLanguagesCreator
    {
        public static List<ApplicationLanguage> InitialLanguages => GetInitialLanguages();

        private readonly SparDbContext _context;

        private static List<ApplicationLanguage> GetInitialLanguages()
        {
            return new List<ApplicationLanguage>
            {
                new ApplicationLanguage(null, "en", "English", "famfamfam-flags gb"),
                new ApplicationLanguage(null, "ar", "???????", "famfamfam-flags sa"),
                new ApplicationLanguage(null, "de", "German", "famfamfam-flags de"),
                new ApplicationLanguage(null, "it", "Italiano", "famfamfam-flags it"),
                new ApplicationLanguage(null, "fr", "Français", "famfamfam-flags fr"),
                new ApplicationLanguage(null, "pt-BR", "Portuguese", "famfamfam-flags br"),
                new ApplicationLanguage(null, "tr", "Türkçe", "famfamfam-flags tr"),
                new ApplicationLanguage(null, "ru", "???????", "famfamfam-flags ru"),
                new ApplicationLanguage(null, "zh-CN", "????", "famfamfam-flags cn"),
                new ApplicationLanguage(null, "es-MX", "Español México", "famfamfam-flags mx"),
                new ApplicationLanguage(null, "nl", "Nederlands", "famfamfam-flags nl"),
                new ApplicationLanguage(null, "ja", "???", "famfamfam-flags jp")
            };
        }

        public DefaultLanguagesCreator(SparDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void Create()
        {
            CreateLanguages();
        }

        private void CreateLanguages()
        {
            foreach (var language in InitialLanguages)
            {
                AddLanguageIfNotExists(language);
            }
        }

        private void AddLanguageIfNotExists(ApplicationLanguage language)
        {
            if (_context.Languages.IgnoreQueryFilters().Any(l => l.TenantId == language.TenantId && l.Name == language.Name))
            {
                return;
            }

            _context.Languages.Add(language);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

It is giving exception for Arabic language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks, @Dalton, and @Lajos for your suggestions, It has really helped in solving the issue.

I have found the solution with the help of your suggestions. This is not EF Core issue, It is the default collation configured in my MySql. So you have to change your default collation on your database. I had **latin1 - default collation**" in the database, which is not useful for inserting Unicode and non-English word(s), Please run the below query to change the collation of all the tables of your database.

```
SELECT CONCAT("ALTER TABLE `", TABLE_NAME,"` convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;") AS    mySQL
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="<YouDatabaseName>"
AND TABLE_TYPE="BASE TABLE"
```

If you don't want to run this query in MySQL, then you can add the above script in the code migration.

Answer (score 2):

Make your database and all tables interclassment as '**utf8_unicode_ci**'
You can do it manually or with executing this query :

Database :

```
ALTER DATABASE <database-name> CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Tables :

```
 ALTER TABLE <table-name> CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Here is [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-change-all-columns-and-tables-collation-to-utf8_bin-in-mysql-601456761.html) with more details and step by step guide

Comment: You can't do it from c# code, if you're using phpmyadmin or any MySQL administrator you can do it manually or from a quey I'll share the query with you.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your SQL, particularly with a varchar you try to assign. Possbile causes:

- you might be using different encoding in your application than the encoding your field expects
- you might be trying to insert a varchar which is longer than the maximum length allowed by your field

Answer (score 1):

Your are using aspnetboilerplate with mysql, to avoid those errors: before migrate, try to change  MySQL database table encoding. It should be UTF-8 (utf8_unicode_ci) for all tables.

Note: if you got "Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes" error running migrations try to change The default storage engine to InnoDB in my.ini

Comment: Cant I change table encoding to UTF-8 from C# code? Or it has to be done manually from MySQL?

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

open `my.ini` file at `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0` then change `default-character-set=latin1` to `default-character-set=utf8` search again and change.